# Neo4j implementing comments

Tags: architecture, neo4j, cypher

In my Spring Boot/Neo4j application I have a big tree of Neo4j nodes and now I would like to implement hierarchical comments for each of these node.

Right now I'm thinking of where these comments must be placed in... In Neo4j database or in some other external RDBMS/NoSQL storage.

Why I'm thinking about it - because of my limited Cypher knowledge right now I'm faced with the problem of removing heavy Neo4j nodes(composite nodes with many relationships to other nodes).. and I can't fix this issue now.. so introducing new Comment nodes can totally kill my system.

So what do you think, should I try to fix the delete issue or implement Comments in some external data storage ?

**UPDATED**

This is my slow delete query:

```
MATCH (d:Decision) 
WHERE id(d) IN {decisionsIds} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]-(t) 
DELETE d, r 
WITH t, r WHERE NOT (id(t) IN {decisionsIds}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[r2:VOTED_ON|:CREATED_BY|:VOTED_FOR]-()-[r3:CONTAINS]-(t2) WHERE r2 <> r 
WITH t, r2, t2, r3 
WHERE none(x in labels(t) 
WHERE x in ['User', 'Decision']) 
DELETE t, r2, t2, r3
```

Right now this query works long time so I afraid to add new entities to Decision node in order to not kill the performance completely.

Is any way to optimize this query ?

Comment: Perhaps provide more details on what you did so far? Your description is pretty vague. In general handling trees of comments is a non-issue for Neo4j.

Comment: I have added my delete query. This query works long time so I afraid to add new entities to Decision node right now

Comment: It would be great if you could share the profile too or a sample database to test it on.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Neo4j 2.2.5 SDN 3.4.0.RELEASE. I'm going to create a sample database right now

Comment: I have added a sample database to my question body

Answer (score 2):

Without a db this is an attempt for a small optimization, not sure if it helps.

It would be also good to know more about the domain model and the cardinalities between the element (e.g. between `d` and `t`)

```
MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE id(d) IN {decisionsIds} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]-(t) 
DELETE d, r 
WITH t, collect(r) as rels 
  WHERE NOT (id(t) IN {decisionsIds}) AND NOT t:User OR t:Decision
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[r2:VOTED_ON|:CREATED_BY|:VOTED_FOR]-(t1)
  WHERE NOT (r2 in rels)
OPTIONAL MATCH (t1)-[r3:CONTAINS]-(t2) 
DELETE t, r2, t2, r3;
```

#### Update

Tested with your DB, worked pretty, well. Regarding your assertions, I'm not sure which ones are violated.

```
export decisionsIds=[332,336,335,334,333,340,339,338,337,344,343,342,341] 

MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE id(d) IN {decisionsIds} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]-(t) 
DELETE d, r 
WITH t, collect(r) as rels 
  WHERE NOT (t:User OR t:Decision) AND NOT (id(t) IN {decisionsIds})
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[r2:VOTED_ON|:CREATED_BY|:VOTED_FOR|:CONTAINS]-(t1)
  WHERE NOT (r2 in rels)
DELETE t, r2
WITH t1
OPTIONAL MATCH (t1)-[:CONTAINS]-(t2) 
// will be detach delete in 2.3
FOREACH ( p IN (t2)--() | DELETE head(rels(p)))
DELETE t2;

+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes deleted: 362
Relationships deleted: 723
340 ms
```

You can find your offending node like this:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n)-[r]-() where id(n) = 86715 return labels(n),n,r;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| labels(n)                  | n                                                                            | r                    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["VoteGroup","_VoteGroup"] | Node[86715]{createDate:"1443124989049",avgVotesWeight:5.0,totalVotesCount:1} | :CONTAINS[173172]{}  |
| ["VoteGroup","_VoteGroup"] | Node[86715]{createDate:"1443124989049",avgVotesWeight:5.0,totalVotesCount:1} | :VOTED_ON[173169]{}  |
| ["VoteGroup","_VoteGroup"] | Node[86715]{createDate:"1443124989049",avgVotesWeight:5.0,totalVotesCount:1} | :VOTED_FOR[173170]{} |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you want to see all data that is touched / would be deleted by this query use this:

```
MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE id(d) IN {decisionsIds} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]-(t) 
WITH t, collect(r) as rels 
  WHERE NOT (t:User OR t:Decision) AND NOT (id(t) IN {decisionsIds})
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[r2:VOTED_ON|:CREATED_BY|:VOTED_FOR|:CONTAINS]-(t1)
  WHERE NOT (r2 in rels)
OPTIONAL MATCH (t1)-[:CONTAINS]-(t2)
RETURN *;
```

Then you can find your offending nodes in the result, and make sure that you deleted everything (every rel-type) around them.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have added sample database to my question body

Comment: I have checked your query.. it works but my assertions in my test failed. It deletes something else also.

Comment: Michael, could you please take a look at db ?

Comment: Not sure what your assertions are.

Comment: What are some sensible id's to use?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work on these IDs - [332,336,335,334,333,340,339,338,337,344,343,342,341]  where 332 is a parent Decision and the rest are descendant Decision nodes with a following exception - `org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException: Node record Node[551,used=false,rel=849,prop=-1,labels=Inline(0x0:[]),light] still has relationships

Neo.DatabaseError.Transaction.CouldNotCommit`

Comment: Even on your query with decisionsIds=[332,333,334,335] I continuously getting  - `Neo.DatabaseError.Transaction.CouldNotCommit`. I tried it with Neo4j 2.2.5 Community and Enterprise versions, SDN 3.4.0.RELEASE

Comment: or for example these id's: `[87074,87084,79773,79779,87076,87075,80392,80389,85419,80391,85422,84872,80386,79771,85418,80390,87082,87083,79782,87081,87079,79780,87080,87077,87078]`  where `87074` is parent ID and the rest are descendant decision IDs. error - `org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException: Node record Node[87886,used=false,rel=175524,prop=-1,labels=Inline(0x0:[]),light] still has relationships`

Comment: `87886` is a `Vote` node, rel `175524` is `CREATED_BY` relationship to `User` node

Comment: And one more case, I can't even delete a single decision for example:  `[86676]` with error - `org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException: Node record Node[86715,used=false,rel=173172,prop=-1,labels=Inline(0x0:[]),light] still has relationships`

Comment: Ok, your t2 also has `CREATED_BY` etc. relationships which you didn't delete. I updated my answer to handle that too.

Comment: Thanks, works on this suite [332,336,335,334,333,340,339,338,337,344,343,342,341]  but still doesn't work on this single id [86676]

Comment: error - `Node record Node[86715,used=false,rel=173172,prop=-1,labels=Inline(0x0:[]),light] still has relationships` where `86715` is a `VoteGroup` node and `173172` is a  `CONTAINS` relationship to `Vote` node

Comment: Is any chance to get this query working in this case also ?

Comment: All the cases above working perfectly now, thanks!  But one of my tests with another database(dynamic,constructed via Neo4j/SDN API in a code) fails with a following exception right now - `Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: Node 140 not found` Where 140 is some `VoteGroup`  Looks like something still wrong with this query..

Comment: I have added another small test database to my question body. During the number of experiments I found that the query doesn't delete `Vote` nodes. For example for these `Decision` id's: `[334,338,339]` after deleting we still have 15 `Vote` nodes but expecting 8.

Comment: Query, that you provided for demonstration what data is touched / would be deleted, shows these `Vote` nodes.. so I don't understand why it is not deleted.. Could you please help to fix the delete query ?

Comment: You know that the t1 nodes are not deleted as of your initial query. I don't know your domain well enough to determine what should be deleted. Perhaps you can take one of these small test databases and make a picture and then mark which nodes and which rels should be deleted.

Comment: Sure, I have added detailed schema. Everything on this diagram must be deleted(nodes and relationships) except `User` node

Comment: Also for clarification - in the delete query I'm passing a list of `Decision` nodes ID's(I'm getting this list by another Cypher query) for example `[334,338,339]` so the delete query doesn't have to find all `Decision` nodes by itself. This query needs to delete all associated nodes(except `User`) and rels according to attached diagram for each `Decision` node from `{decisionsIds}`.

Comment: Could you please help me to resolve this issue ? I am stuck from quite a long time.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
MATCH (u:User {id:"Alex"})
MATCH (u)-[r:CREATED_BY]->(n)
OPTIONAL MATCH path = (n)<-[:VOTED_FOR|:VOTED_ON|:CONTAINS]-()
DELETE n,r,path
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think it will not work because the different nodes in this schema(at the diagram above) can be created by different `Users` so we need to start the query from `{decisionsIds}`. Also, these Users can create as many different Decision trees as they want but I need to delete only specific ones in `{decisionsIds}`

Comment: Query in your previous answer(not in this) is really close to what exactly I need except that this query doesn't delete the `Vote` nodes. `Vote` nodes must be also deleted together with `VoteGroup` nodes